# Change Partion Drive Space

Tags: linux, lvm, fdisk

Okay I am having some trouble here - pretty new to the Linux environment and need some help. I have a 2.7 TB RAID array, and someone configured a partition at around 200 GB but it really needs to be larger like 2.2 TB. How do I Make the partition larger?

Also it looks like there is a duplicate 2.2 TB partition.

I need the disk, `/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_home`, 219.9 GB partition, to be the 2.2 TB, and I am not sure how/if I can resize that partition or if I need to make something new and copy content over.

Here is some information from some commands I've run.

List of Discs using `fdisk`

```
[root@orchestrator1 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 299.4 GB, 299439751168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36404 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d0e98

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64       36405   291908608   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 2698.6 GB, 2698581639168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 328083 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3d468517

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1       60735   487849952+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6527 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_swap: 25.4 GB, 25367150592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3084 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/3600508e000000000cad0b2b5c22f8d02: 2698.6 GB, 2698581639168 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 328083 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3d468517

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mapper/3600508e000000000cad0b2b5c22f8d02p1               1       60735   487849952+  83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/3600508e000000000cad0b2b5c22f8d02p1: 2199.0 GB, 2199020350464 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267348 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

Disk /dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_home: 219.9 GB, 219857027072 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 26729 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/3600508e000000000cad0b2b5c22f8d02p1p1: 2199.0 GB, 2199020318208 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 267348 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

`df -h` command

```
[root@orchestrator1 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_root
                   50G   45G  1.7G  97% /
tmpfs                  24G   80K   24G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M  123M  325M  28% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_home
                  202G   61M  192G   1% /home
```

And `cat /etc/fstab` command:

```
[root@orchestrator1 ~]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Mon Apr 27 13:14:35 2015
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_root /                       ext4   defaults        1 1
UUID=62e2c26b-9f29-4de4-96b1-d76ff142d23d /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_orchestrator1-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb                /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
```

pvs

```
[root@orchestrator1 ~]# pvs
  PV  VG               Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3600508e000000000e30eb35adb098c03-part2 vg_orchestrator1 lvm2 a--  278.38g    0
```

lvs

```
[root@orchestrator1 ~]# lvs
LV   VG  Attr LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
lv_home vg_orchestrator1 -wi-ao---- 204.76g
lv_root vg_orchestrator1 -wi-ao----  50.00g
lv_swap vg_orchestrator1 -wi-ao----  23.62g
```

Comment: Please take a look at the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and edit your post.  As it is it's pretty much unreadable.

Comment: Looks like you're using LVM. Could you please include the output of `pvs` and `lvs`?

Comment: We are Using Oracle Linux

Comment: The system-config-lvm command doesn't seem to work

Comment: please add pvdisplay and vgdisplay output